# Help with a Cox Proportional Hazard Simulation in R

Tags: r, simulation, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I am trying to follow along with a scientific journal. I am not used to running simulations so I could use a little help in R.

Here is the simulation from the paper.

> For each experiment, we generate a training, validation, and testing
>   set of N = 5000 observations, such that an observation represents a
>   patient vector with d = 10 covariates, each drawn from a uniform
>   distribution on [1; 1). We generate the death time T according to an
>   exponential Cox model:
>
> $T\sim Exp(\lambda(t;x))=Exp(\lambda_0\cdot e^{-h(x)})$
>
> In both experiments, the risk function h(x) only depends on two of the
>   ten covariates, and we demonstrate that DeepSurv is able to discern
>   the relevant covariates from the noise. We then choose a censoring
>   time to represent the ‘end of study,’ such that an average of 30-40
>   percent of the patients have an observed event in the dataset.
>
> We first simulate patients to have a linear risk function for $x \in
> > R^{d}$ so that the linear proportional hazards assumption holds true:
>
> $h(x)=x_0+2x_1$
>
> Because the linear proportional hazards assumption holds true, we
>   expect the linear CPH to accurately model the risk function [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00931)

[[1] Jared L. Katzman1, (2016), 'Deep Survival: A Deep Cox Proportional Hazards Network', arxiv.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.00931)

This is what I have so far

```
set.seed(42)

#50,000 random uniforms
obs <- runif(50000,min = -1, max = .999)

#make uniforms a matrix
obs <- matrix(data = obs, nrow = 5000, ncol = 10)

#is_censored
is_censored <- sample(0:1,5000,TRUE,prob=c(0.40,0.60))

#time ??
```

I have the random uniform `5000x10` matrix and the column that will indicate censoring. I still need the time till death column which is where I am getting stuck. I am not sure how to pull $T$ from the distribution they specified and how to simulate the dependence of the first two covariates  $h(x)=x_0+2x_1$

Comment: To state my question more clearly: 1. How to I get the column that represents the time to death. 2. How do I simulate the dependance structure of the risk function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a partial answer. The `survsim` package in R provides a way to model survival times[1](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i02).

I am still unable to figure out how to simulate dependance between two covariates.

[[1]](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v059i02)The R Package survsim for the Simulation of Simple
and Complex Survival Data